# How do I encode address field when creating new instance of a contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs

when I query my accounts on my local test rpc, I get this:

```
> web3.eth.accounts[0]

'0x8a39ab283fb500e3be48a68f6c9d90371bfaa345'
```

All good, but when I try to create an instance of a contract I created, I get this:

```
> deployedContract = VotingContract.new(['Larry','Curly','Moe'], { data: contract.bytecode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000})

Error: invalid argument 0: missing 0x prefix for hex data
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\dude\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:38:16)
    at RequestManager.send (C:\Users\dude\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:61:22)
    at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (C:\Users\dude\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\method.js:145:58)
    at ContractFactory.new (C:\Users\dude\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\contract.js:228:33)
    at repl:1:38
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:313:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
>
```

What is the correct format for the address in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The problem wasn't with the address, it was with the bytecode.  I just needed to prefix the bytecode with '0x', i.e.:

```
> deployedContract = VotingContract.new(['Larry','Curly','Moe'], { data: '0x'.concat(contract.bytecode), from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000})
```